# Use pytesseract OCR to recognize text from an image?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

i am trying to write a simple python script that looks at an image and prints out the name and numbers beside the name it works out of the box now but it picks up data it shouldnt and if anyone can help to hold to fix it so it doesnt would be great.

as you can see in the image below it picks up the bottom border of each name as EE--
how can i filter it so it only picks up the name and the numbers.

[image]

Comment: Let me be quite frank.  OCR is an inexact science.  The results you are getting are very, very good.  You would be better served not dinking with the OCR and just remove the EE lines from your output.

Comment: Could you share the original source image without the red boxes, please.